# Unable to access custom response header in frontend application

Tags: http, go, http-headers, axios

I am having trouble getting access to a custom respoone header being provided by our backend server. Server is written in Go. I am attempting to access it using axios as my HTTP client. I can see the header in the chrome dev-tools console, but I cannot get access to the header through axios.

chrome dev tools response headers. I am looking to get the x-***-token at the bottom
[image: chrome dev tools . response headers]

headers I have access to through axios (cors enabled)
[image: headers I have access to through axios]

I can, however, access the header through axios when I run chrome with cors disabled:

`open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security`

headers I have access to through axios (cors disabled)
[image]

This tells me that its not an issue with axios, but with the header configuration I have.

Below is how we have configured our headers, I am trying to get access the ***x-custom-token*** header:

```
func allowCORS(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" && contains(cors, origin) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
    }
    if contains(cors, "*") {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    }

    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" || r.Method == "GET" && r.Header.Get("Access-Control-Request-Method") != "" &&
        w.Header().Get("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") != "" {
        headers := []string{"Content-Type", "Accept-Encoding", "X-CSRF-Token", "Authorization", "accept", "origin", "Cache-Control", "X-Requested-With", "x-custom-token"}
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", strings.Join(headers, ","))
        methods := []string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"}
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", strings.Join(methods, ","))
        expose := []string{"x-custom-token"}
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", strings.Join(expose, ","))
        return
    }
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})}
```

Can anyone tell me what header I have set incorrectly?

Comment: Just a guess, but capitalizing those header strings using http.CanonicalHeaderKey before using them to set headers might help.

Comment: @CeriseLimón What I meant is the headers set for Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Expose-Headers, they have `x-custom-token`, etc. Those are as header values, not header keys.

Comment: I have updated the post with screenshots of the response headers shown in chrome and the console output from axios

Comment: @CeriseLimón it works with an OPTIONS request, but the headers are not exposed on a GET (or any other method), which is what is needed by axios https://play.golang.org/p/SwDHlWfVVlx

Comment: @bserdar Headers are case-insensitive. See RFC2616 Sec 4.2 https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are only exposing for OPTIONS requests.

In your if statement, one of your criteria are `r.Header.Get("Access-Control-Request-Method") != ""`.

This header is typically only ever used in pre-flight requests and so your expose headers are not getting written on GET or other methods.

In addition, your statement returns after writing the headers. This is correct for pre-flight but would cause no content to be sent for other methods.

Solution - adjust your logic to handle exposing headers separately from the pre-flight headers.