# Unable to fetch custom header in post response using Angular 10

Tags: angular, webapi

I am trying to get custom header from Angular 10 client post response. I am able to see it in Browser Dev Network window though, but not in my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge9J9.png)

I am fetching the custom header on Angular side using the following code:

const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) ,    withCredentials: false,
};

this.loading = true;

```
  const postedData = { userId : this.f.username.value, password : this.f.password.value, token: "string" };
  this.http.post<any>("https://localhost:44365/api/v1/Credential/", postedData, httpOptions)
  .subscribe(
      data => {
          this.currentUser= data;
          var txt = this.http.options.toString();
          var token = data.headers.get('X_Custom_header');
          var token1 = httpOptions.headers.get('X_Custom_header');
          console.log(data);
          debugger;
```

Have gone through one similar article but it seems the code for fetching the header would be different here in Angular:
[Unable to access custom response header in frontend application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263373/unable-to-access-custom-response-header-in-frontend-application)

Please correct me if there should be any change on Angular side code while reading custom header.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See http Option "observe" "Response" in the documentation https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to get this header by writing the following code on server side:

app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().WithExposedHeaders("X_Custom_header"));  //(Works)

instead of following code:

app.UseCors("AllowAll"); //(Does not work)

It was quite strange that even I was getting the custom header on Browser, I was not able to access it using simple HTTP post response as I showed in attached screenshot. But just after adding the above code, I got it on Angular client side.

@krosan : I did not try your approach. But thanks for providing direction.